# update manager for updating computers on a network (linux)

Tags: linux, networking, update

Is there some kind of open source software available that manages updates to various computers on a network? for linux in general, ubuntu/debian in particular. I intend to build one such system for ubuntu where updates to some computers on a network is administered by an admin/master computer which can manage updates to these computers. If you can point me to any existing update managers that do this, or any article or journal I can refer to for implementing such kind of a system.

Comment: +1 - interested as well, as long as it isn't some crazy Puppet piece-meal. :)

Comment: Just FYI, looks like this project had the idea, just no approval/launch - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UpdateServer , also it appears like I was thinking that Puppet Enterprise http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/puppet-enterprise/ might work if you are willing to go that route

Comment: [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: Thank you @TheCleaner.. UbuntuServer is pretty much what I intend to build.. but not on a large scale..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spacewalk is primarily for Red Hat distros, but the FAQ lists Debian as a supported OS as well.

http://spacewalk.redhat.com/faq.html#compare

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty broad space. You can use tools such as:

- [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/)
- [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/)
- [cfengine](http://cfengine.com/)

... to create "rules" to manage remote systems. There are provisioning systems such as:

- [cobbler](http://cobbler.github.com/)
- [spacewalk](http://spacewalk.redhat.com/)

Here is a review of 5 such systems: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/server-provisioning-software.html.

Answer (score 2):

And one more tool one should at least look at :)

https://landscape.canonical.com/

From the landscape home-page

"Make the most of Ubuntu with Landscape

The Landscape systems management tool helps you monitor, manage and update your entire Ubuntu infrastructure from a single interface. Part of Canonical’s Ubuntu Advantage support service, Landscape brings you intuitive systems management tools combined with world-class support. "